# Would a simulacrum created by a simulacrum of a caster that can cast simulacrum remain behind if the original simulacrum is destroyed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, simulacrum

A simulacrum of a caster can use magic, or this line would not make sense:

> [...] nor can it regain expended Spell Slots.

But a caster can only have one simulacrum:

> If **you** cast this spell again, any currently active duplicates **you created** with this spell are instantly destroyed.

The simulacrum is not the caster, it is a different creature. Since it has spell slots and the statistics of the caster (Including the spellcasting trait), it could cast simulacrum too. And the duplicate created by the simulacrum's casting is not created by the caster.

So, here is the scenario:

- Suppose Anne, a caster [class redacted] can cast simulacrum.
- Anne creates a simulacrum, and names her Betty.
- Anne commands Betty to cast simulacrum, using a strand of Anne's hair. Christine is created.
- Anne then (maybe after a long rest) casts simulacrum (of herself) again, creating Dorothy. Betty is Instantly Destroyed.

Since ongoing spell effects do not depend on the caster to continue on, This may leave Anne with Christine and Dorothy, both able to cast simulacrum.

Is there any flaw in the reasoning above? Is it allowed by RAW?

Comment: While fairly distinct, this question is quite close to the top [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79841/ "What is the maximum number of simulacra I can have?"), regarding the maximum number of simulacra possible, or at least it is answerable with the answers there. Especially the part with the Adventurers' League FAQ entry regarding simulacrum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Rules As Written

*[Simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum)* specifically says the duplicate...

> ...can take actions and otherwise be affected as a normal creature.

Two normal creatures who cast *Simulacrum* would not be adversely affected by each other's casting, so there's no reason to believe one simulacrum's casting would affect the original caster's.

## Food For Thought

For D&D Adventurers League organized play, they felt the need to explicitly prohibit even trying this. The [D&D Adventurers League FAQ](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208179/DD-Adventurers-League-DM-Pack) says...

> ### Simulacrum
>
> The following guidance applies:
>
> ***No Copies of a Copy***. Simulacrums can’t cast *simulacrum*, or any spell that duplicates its effects.

If they need to prohibit something *for organized play* not specifically denied in the RAW indicates that it may very well be RAI. I can't provide any hard quotes, but there was conversation in Facebook groups about this DDAL-specific caveat being to reduce complexity and GM load in organized play. It doesn't reflect on normal play.

Comment: Terrible movie reference may apply here... Multiplicity with Michael Keaton, they cloned a clone with interesting side effects... a DM could do that to their players :) might not be RAW but definitely could be a plot hook.

Comment: @slagmoth since they are all using hairs from Alice, it is not really a clone of a clone. Now to ask if a simulacrum can donate body pieces to make simulacra

Comment: @Mindwin It's not a *clone* at all... that's a different spell. ;)

Comment: @Slagmoth As much as I was teasing Mindwin, *Simulacrum* is more like cloning as described in Multiplicity. In fact, the rules bear out the replicative fading - Assuming two L7 slots and barring hijinks from answers on the related question, the second order simulacrums only have one (because one gets spent) and half as many HP as the original. Third order simulacri are as far as you can go; they have no 7th level slots to continue and they have a quarter of the HP of the original.

Comment: @T.J.L. this is why they are all simulacra of Anne's: "[...] Betty to cast simulacrum, *using a strand of Anne's hair.* Christine is created" - they copy Anne's spell slots, not the simulacrum caster.

Comment: @Mindwin Right, you're doing all first-order simulacrums, which is the way to avoid replicative fading. In the film Slagmoth was talking about, there are a couple of first order clones and at least one second order clone.